# Want to know Permission Condition of a book

Tags: copyright

I bought a book from local vendor who buy books from foreign countries and then re-sell them. Book publisher name is Penguin

On the book, The following has been written:

> Except in the United States of America, this book is sold subject to 
>       the condition that it shall not, by way of trade or otherwise, be 
>       lent, re-sold, hired out, or otherwise circulated without the 
>       publisher's prior consent in any form of binding or cover other than 
>       that in which it is published and without a similar condition 
>       including this condition being imposed upon the subsequent purchaser.

My query is, what does this mean actually ? Re-selling is not allowed over here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that a person cannot put a new cover or binding on a book, and then resell it or lend it, unless permission is obtained from the publisher. This has the effect of prohibiting libraries, which need to rebind most books, from carrying the book without the publisher's permission. This condition did not apply in the US, because under the US Law's *First Sale Doctrine*, the seller cannot impose such conditions on the buyer.

The very standardize wording was, I think, once part of the [Net book Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Book_Agreement) (NBA) used by Penguin and other UK-based publishers on sales in the UK and the Commonwealth. You will find it on many used books from such publishers. I believe the main aim was to prohibit discount resellers of used books, and to prohibit sale of "stripped books" (reported to the publisher as "unsold and destroyed"). I believe that this is no longer in effect, but I am not sure. The NBA was dissolved in 1995.